# Could we replace human DNA

Tags: biology, technology

I was reading an infographic online talking about the future of humanity and it said 7,000 years from now, humans could replace their DNA with xDNA, which would be stabler, triply redundant and less liable to mutation. Could this be feasible? Could it be feasible for humans to do this?

Comment: The _entire history_ from the earliest cuneiform clay tables to the latest iPhone spans about 5000 years. What technologies will be available 7000 years from now is beyond man's capacity of prediction and understanding.

Comment: Arthur C. Clarke's [third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws) suggests that "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."  Given that the time range is 7,000 years from now, anything at all is possible.  So, yes, it's feasible.

Comment: I agree that this thing is possible, as in "reality-check passed". However, I would disagree that "anything is possible 7000 years for now". We have "realty-check" tag for a reason, after all (and I suggest putting it here).

Comment: We can design error-correcting DNA today (it won't function biologically), it wouldn't be impossible to imagine it being possible in the future to replace our own DNA with something like it.

Comment: an "organic" human... nice!

Comment: Evolution-wise I doubt a less liable to mutation DNA is really wanted. if it was so, we would still be merrily swimming in the primordial soup...

Comment: @Alexander We may [get rid of reality-check in the near future](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/do-we-need-the-reality-check-tag).

Comment: you guess you never know ..